# cloudmonkey with crontab?

Tags: apache-cloudstack

i have a Cloudstack 4.2.1 here and would like my VMs to boot from time and shutdown at a scheduled time.
Hence i was thinking if i could integrate Cloudmonkey with CronTab together. 
Firstly by creating a Cloudmonkey Script or API call then using crontab to run it at a specific time.

However i have problems creating a Cloudmonkey script/API call...

i haved googled and found this link

http://dlafferty.blogspot.sg/2013/07/using-cloudmonkey-to-automate.html

and had a result of

apiresult=`cloudmonkey api stop virtualmachine   id="'e10bdf21-2d5c-4277-9d8d-791b82b9e3be'"`

unfortunately when i entered this command, nothing happened. If anyone could have an alternative suggestion or rather my API call command is wrong, please correct me and help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudMonkey requires some setup before it works (e.g. setting your API key).
Check [1] for the documentation for CloudMoney and follow through the Usage section to setup your environment.

Once your setup is complete and you can interact with CloudStack via CloudMonkey, you should take into account that the VM ids might change, so before you issue a command for a VM, you should first find the correct id, by listing the VMs and picking the right one.

Also, if you run into trouble, post the relevant log from CLoudStack management server (typically in `/var/log/cloudstack/management/management-server.log`).

[1] - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/CloudStack+cloudmonkey+CLI

**Edit**: If you have a working connection via CloudMonkey to CloudStack, you need to configure CloudMonkey in the same way in your shell script. For instance when you configured CloudMonkey you probably set a host, a port and your api and secret keys. So for your scrip to work you need to provide the same configuration to CloudMonkey prior to issuing the commands. My best guess is to use the `-c` option and provide a config file to set all the relevant parameters (e.g. api an secret key). `cloudmonkey -c CONFIG_FILE ....`

**Edit2**: You don't actually need to re-configure cloudmonkey in your script because it will remember your config from the interactive session. I would still advise you to do it, because your script gets more reliable. I've just made an example script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
result=$(cloudmonkey list users)
echo $result
```

Result:

```
> ./tmp.sh
count = 1 user: id = 678e3a24-082c-11e4-86de-acbdb2423647 account = admin accountid = 678dffe6-082c-11e4-86de-acbdb2423647 accounttype = 1 apikey = T6sDBIpytyJ4_PMgNXYi8YgjMtwTiiDjijbXNB1J78EAZq2foKhCoGKjgJnej5tMaHM0LUvejgTddkhVU63wdw created = 2014-07-10T16:19:13+0200 domain = ROOT domainid = 678dd7b4-082c-11e4-86de-acbdb2423647 email = admin@mailprovider.com firstname = Admin iscallerchilddomain = False isdefault = True lastname = User secretkey = dzOPRecI5vvEVK7Vie2D0tDsQGXunUnpIAczbXnPI3sfMwQ-upWL_bPOisEYg4C-nXi-ldQno2KVZbVR-5NmVw state = enabled username = admin
```

Maybe you forgot to `echo`the result?

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the syntax of the script for cloudmonkey and you provided me with the answer! Now it's working!!! Really appreciate your help! haha i am still a linux newbie